# GCP Bigquery: Can't query stackdriver access logs exported in cloudstorage because invalid json field "@type"

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver

I store the access log of a pixel image in a cloudstorage bucket `dev-access-log-bucket` using the standard "sink"

so the files looks like this `requests/2019/05/08/15:00:00_15:59:59_S1.json` 
and one line looks like this (I formatted the json, but it's on one line normmaly) :

```
{
  "httpRequest": {
    "cacheLookup": true,
    "remoteIp": "93.24.25.190",
    "requestMethod": "GET",
    "requestSize": "224",
    "requestUrl": "https://dev-snowplow.legalstart.fr/one_pixel_image.png?user_id=0&action=purchase&product_id=0&money=10",
    "responseSize": "779",
    "status": 200,
    "userAgent": "python-requests/2.21.0"
  },
  "insertId": "w6wyz1g2jckjn6",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
    "statusDetails": "response_sent_by_backend"
  },
  "logName": "projects/tracking-pixel-239909/logs/requests",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2019-05-08T15:34:24.126095758Z",
  "resource": {
    "labels": {
      "backend_service_name": "",
      "forwarding_rule_name": "dev-yolaw-pixel-forwarding-rule",
      "project_id": "tracking-pixel-239909",
      "target_proxy_name": "dev-yolaw-pixel-proxy",
      "url_map_name": "dev-urlmap",
      "zone": "global"
    },
    "type": "http_load_balancer"
  },
  "severity": "INFO",
  "spanId": "7d8823509c2dc94f",
  "timestamp": "2019-05-08T15:34:23.140747307Z",
  "trace": "projects/tracking-pixel-239909/traces/bb55577eedd5797db2867931f8de9162"
}
```

all of these once again are standard GCP things, I did not customize anything here.

So now I want to do some requests on it from Bigquery, I create a dataset and an external table configured like this :

```
External Data Configuration
Source URI(s) gs://dev-access-log-bucket/requests/*
Auto-detect schema true   (note: I don't know why it puts true though i've manually defined it)
Ignore unknown values true
Source format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
Max bad records 0
```

and the following manual schema:

```
timestamp   DATETIME    REQUIRED    
httpRequest     RECORD  REQUIRED    
httpRequest. requestUrl     STRING  REQUIRED
```

and when I run a request

```
SELECT
  timestamp
FROM
  `path.to.my.table`
LIMIT
  1000
```

I got

Invalid field name "@type". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

How can I work around this without needing to pre-process the log to not have the "@type" field in it ?

Comment: I guess if you try to `bq load` the data as a table, you will encounter same error but maybe worth trying.

Comment: @YunZhang I will have a try, for the moment i've worked around the problem by choosing bigquery directly as the sink

Comment: Sounds like a better idea than `bq load`.

Comment: I noticed that the issue was solved by selecting BigQuery as the preferred sink. I only want to provide more insights on the error since most probably old logs were used with the [extended field name @type](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery#type-specifier). I was able to find [a feature request for managing older logs](https://issuetracker.google.com/111878351), you can star it to manifest your interest on it.